# Do Father's facial features change?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm not sure how to write this without implying a spoiler, so don't read on if you haven't met Father yet.

I seem to recall Dad's features changing depending upon how you designed your character in Fallout 3.

In Fallout 4, I can't decide if Father's features change. I tried making a black character, and found that his skin tone changed to match, but he still looked pretty much the same.

Has anyone tested this? How much do they change, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

They do, in fact, change, though since it is a blend of the mother *and* father, you may not see a huge difference without changing both of their appearances. Here is a [compilation](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3wywlk/storyline_spoiler_the_many_faces_of_shaun/) of different faces for Father.

Comment: I opened a bunch of browser windows, and looked at six pictures side-by-side: Default Parents, Default Father, Weird Blond Parents, Weird Blond Father, Black Parents, and Black Father. Although the skin color obviously changes, as I noted in the question, the facial features of the different parents are so similar that I can't actually tell if the facial features of Father are changing. Can you tell the difference between the blonde Father and the default Father? I think they only changed the hair on the parents anyway.

Comment: @DCShannon I had to look very closely, as they are very similar, but I believe that the blonde Father and the default Father have slightly different mouth and eye shapes. The blonde Father's mouth is slightly wider and thinner than the default and the eyes are a tiny bit squintier.